# Loose plug socket, is it safe to tighten outer screws

Tags: electrical, socket

sorry probably a stupid question but the front of my plug socket has come loose from the back box, is it safe to just tighten the outer screws? It's a UK plug socket with 2 outlets and the loose screws are on the left and right hand side so not touching any wires I assume,  but would turn the power off first just incase. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the power is off at the breaker, it is safe tighten any screws.

Those screws are probably safe even with the power on, but you never know if that is the time you slip and touch a hot wire.

It takes much less time time to turn off the right breaker and to double check the power is off, than hoping the closest hospital can save you.

It is not safe to have a loose socket, so it will depend on why the screws are loose, to know if just tightening them is all that is needed.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply and reassuring me, I will definitely turn all power off before I go near it :)

Comment: UK uses 240 volts and that bites a lot harder than NA 120 volts.  Electricity is useful, but must respect it.

Comment: All sorted now, it just needed a quick tightening up, thanks again